# onTouchEvent to mark on map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, touch-event

I am working on Location reminder project. I want to mark on the location where it is touched. I have created 3 classes:GoogleDemo3, MapOverlay1 and MapOverlay. 
MapOverlay1 class is inner class of GoogleDemo3. MapOverlay1 class draws marker on the map in given location. MapOverlay should return the geopoint when map is touched on certain location. So with the help of that returned geopoint MapOverlay1 is supposed to draw mark. But it keeps giving uncaught exception. Here are the codes:
    package in.out.google.demo;

```
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class GoogleDemo3 extends MapActivity 
{    
MapView mapView; 
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;

class MapOverlay1 extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
        return true;
    }

}
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_demo3);

    mapView=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.MapView);

    mc = mapView.getController();



    //---Add a location marker---
    MapOverlay1 mapOverlay1 = new MapOverlay1();
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this,mapView); 
    p=mapOverlay.geopoint();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay1);        
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 

    mapView.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

And I created one more class MapOverlay

```
package in.out.google.demo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class MapOverlay extends Overlay{
Context c;
GeoPoint p;
MapView mapView;
public MapOverlay(Context context, MapView mapView){
    this.c=context;
    this.mapView=mapView;
    }

  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
  {   
      //---when user lifts his finger---
      MapView mapView;
      mapView=this.mapView;

      if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
          GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
              (int) event.getX(),
              (int) event.getY());
              Toast.makeText(c, 
                  p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + 
                  p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                this.p=p;
      }
        return false;              
} 
  public GeoPoint geopoint(){
      return this.p;
  }
}
```

Please help for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having now, results from the following:

```
p=mapOverlay.geopoint();
```

`p` gets a null value in this line, as the value of `p` in class `MapOverlay` as not yet been initialized.

In `MapOverlay` replace:

```
GeoPoint p;
```

by something like:

```
GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(nnn, mmm);
```

Beside that, you still have some issues with your code:

- You are decoding the `BitMap` everytime the overlay is drawn. That should be done in the overlay constructor.
- You are always returning `false` from `onTouchEvent()`, and that will make it impossible to differentiate between map movement and touch to add markers.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It vanished the exception. The icon drawn on the map because I initialized to geopoint p = new Geopoint(lat,long) as you told.  But when touch on the map, it just doesn't respond. Touch event is inside the class MapOverlay, it is supposed to return the geopoint p to main method of class GoogleDemo3, and then using this geopoint the class MapOverlay1 should draw icon on the map. touch event is not responding.